# cleartool lsstream -tree get only list of child streams

Tags: cleartool

I want to list get list of child streams under a given stream.

`cleartool lsstream -tree` gets all streams **and** activities under it.
How can print only the stream-names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [fmt_ccase](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) to mention exactly the kind of information you want:

```
cleartool describe -fmt "%[dstreams]CXp" stream:myStream@\myPVob
```

That would give you *one* line of:

```
stream:streamA@MyPvob, stream:streamC@MyPvob, stream:streamC@MyPvob, ...
```

So there would still be a bit of processing to do, but at least you would have *only* what you were after: the child streams of a given Stream.