# ClearCase: how to list non-obsolete sub-streams?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have an integration stream in ClearCase. I want to get a list with the names of all of its child streams that aren't marked as obsolete. Which command should I run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `cleartool lsstream -tree myIntStream@\myPvob` should be enough.
(Unix:  `cleartool lsstream -tree myIntStream@/vobs/myPvob`)

As mentioned in [`cleartool lsstream`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsstream.htm):

> Default
>
> Lists only nonobsolete streams.

[neves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10335/neves) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535833/clearcase-how-to-list-non-obsolete-sub-streams/25535967#comment39902382_25535967):

> This also list all the activities of the stream. I think it is necessary to pass something the fmt option. I'd like just the name of the streams.

As I mention in "[`cleartool lsstream -tree` get only list of child streams](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5366797/6309)" (using [`fmt_ccase`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm)):

```
cleartool describe -fmt "%[dstreams]CXp" stream:myStream@\myPVob
```

The [OP neves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10335/neves) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535833/clearcase-how-to-list-non-obsolete-sub-streams/25535967?noredirect=1#comment39946903_25535967) having just the names with:

```
 cleartool describe -fmt "%[dstreams]p" stream:myStream@\myPVo
```

Comment: This also list all the activities of the stream. I think it is necessary to pass something the fmt option. I'd like just the name of the streams.

Comment: @neves Ok, I have edited the answer with an alternative solution

Comment: I've got just the names with this comand: cleartool describe -fmt "%[dstreams]p" stream:myStream@\myPVob . I'll use it in Hudson to automatically build the active streams.

Comment: @neves Indeed. I have included your command in the answer for ore visibility.